# How to get an array index in erb template in puppet

Tags: erb, puppet

I need to be able to generate following content of the file (for zookeeper installation):

```
server.1=$zk.server1.full.hostname:2888:3888
server.2=$zk.server2.full.hostname:2888:3888
server.3=$zk.server3.full.hostname:2888:3888
```

when I have an array of server hostnames (example shows # of servers = 3). I tried something like following:

```
<% @regionserver_list.each do |this_server| -%>
server.  =<%= this_server %>:2888:3888
<% end -%>
```

That seems not correct as and I am struggling with getting an array index (need to start from 1). The point here is that the list of servers will be variable so I cannot use workaround with putting fixed template here for time being. I am stuck on this, can someone help?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
<% @quorumserver_list.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |this_server, idx| -%>
<%= "server.#{idx}=#{this_server}:2888:3888" %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: The string interpolation did not work for me with Ruby 2.0.0. It actually kick the interpreter's scope out of the template and into its parent scope.

Which version of Ruby were you using?